# How can I display required html 5 in vue component?

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

My vue component like this :

```
<template>
    <div>
        ...
        <form class="form-horizontal" id="form-profile">
            ...
            <input type="number" class="form-control" required>
            ...
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" @click="submit">Submit</button>
            ...
        </form>
        ...
    </div>
</template>
<script>
    export default {
        ...
        methods: {
            submit(e) {
                e.preventDefault()
                if (this.checkForm()) {
                    // do ajax here
                }
            },
            checkForm() {
                let field = true
                $('#form-profile :required').each(function(i) {
                    if(this.checkValidity() == false) 
                        field = false
                })
                return field
            },
        }
    }
</script>
```

I using required html5 to validation

I using `e.preventDefault()` to prevent page redirects. Because I want to using ajax

My problem here is the required validation html5 not show if not filled. Maybe it because I using `e.preventDefault()`

How can I display the required html5?

Comment: Use vuejs `@click.prevent` instead of `e.preventDefault`

Comment: @u_mulder,I had using `@click="submit"` on the tag button submit. Do I have to use 2 `@click`

Comment: `@click.prevent="submit"` Follow a manual please https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html#Event-Modifiers

Comment: @u_mulder It's the same. It does not work. The required html5 is not show

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In order to work as expected you have to set the `v-on:submit` method on the form tag, and have a button/input type "submit".

Also, notice the event modifier `prevent` on the `@submit`, it's a shorcut to not have to write `e.preventDefault()` on the method

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      myText: ''
    }
  },
  methods: {
    submitForm() {
      alert('submited: ' + this.myText)
    }
  },
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.15/vue.js"></script>


<div id="app">
  <form @submit.prevent="submitForm">
    <input type="text" v-model="myText" required />
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
  </form>
</div>
```